# Does gfortran generate random numbers more slowly than MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, random, fortran, gfortran

I am a first-time user of Fortran and am performing an elementary performance comparison of Fortran vs. Matlab by sampling random numbers (suppressed output). With an MWE, in Fortran (.f95 file):

```
program main
  real(4) :: r
  integer i
  do i = 1,50000000
    call random_number(r)
  enddo
end program main
```

And in MATLAB (.m file):

```
for i = 1:50000000
  rand();
end
```

When I compile the Fortran code using gfortran (v4.5.3), the executable runs about 3x slower than the MATLAB (r2011b) code. As it stands, is this an expected outcome?

Comment: Note that your programs are not equivalent - the default datatype in Matlab is typically equivalent to real(8) in gfortran; you are not saving the result of the rand call in matlab.  Please state the command line options you used for the gfortran compile.  "MWE"?  There are many different random number generators out there that differ in terms of execution efficiency and quality.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @IanH. Neither altering `real(4)` to `real(8)` nor saving `rand()` to a variable has any perceptible effect. Building the minimal working example (MWE) in gfortran, I run `gfortran example.f95 -o example.exe` (with and without an optimizer e.g., -O3 at the end of the command) under Windows 7...

Comment: is it possible that matlab is not actually calling `rand()?` Since it can see the `;` at the end of the line which means do not print, and you are also not assigning the result to anything so the matlab interpreter might not be calling `rand();` just making a fast empty loop while with Fortran the call is actually being made.

Answer (score 4):

As IanH pointed out, you are actually comparing single and double precision. If I change your Fortran code to double precision, I get an extra ~2x slow-down.

The reason for the speed difference is probably the fact that Matlab and gfortran use different implementations of different algorithms: Matlab uses the Mersenne twister PRNG, whereas gfortran uses George Marsaglia's KISS PRNG.

Comment: Yes, because the standard imposes very weak requirements for the choice of the PRNG, one should not rely on it in performance critical applications or applications connected security. Especially if you don't know which compiler will the end user use.